# How to avoid warning "mutating a prop directly" using Vue and Laravel

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I am using Laravel 7 and Vue.js 2.
I want to pass an eloquent query result from a controller to a Vue.js component (passing through a View and another component).

This is my controller:

```
$permissions = Permission::select('id')->get();

return view('admin')->with(['permissions'=>$permissions]);
```

This is my view:

```
<div id="app">
    <admin-panel :permissions="{{  $permissions }}"></admin-panel>
</div>
```

This is `admin-panel` component (passing data through props):

```
<template>
    <div>
        <admin-operations></admin-operations>    
        <hr>
        <insert-employee :permissions="permissions"></insert-employee></div>
</template>
```

This is `insert-employee` component script:

```
<script>

    export default {
        components: {
        },
        props: ['permissions'],
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.');
        },
        computed:{
        },
        data: function() {
            return {
            }
        },
        methods: {
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is the select in `insert-employee` component:

```
        <select required v-model="permissions" class="form-control" id="permissions">
            <option v-for="permission in permissions" :value="permission.id" :key="permission.id">
                {{ permission.id }}
            </option>
        </select>
```

The results of the query should be visualized in the select options.
However in the select I can visualize correctly the values in the options, but when I select an option the selection doesn't work and in the console appears two times the following warning:

```
app.js:40160 [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "permissions"

found in

---> <InsertEmployee> at resources/js/components/InsertEmployee.vue
       <AdminPanel> at resources/js/components/AdminPanel.vue
         <Root>
```

Can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this. I *think* we're just mixing the values up a bit. I'll try to think of props that are passed in as a read only thing. In this case `permissions` is an array that holds the id's of each permission.

Next we'll want to use that array to give our `user` object some values. This way we aren't trying to manipulate values of `permissions`. That's where Vue was initially getting angry.

```
<script>
    export default {
        components: {},
    
        props: {
            permissions: {
                type: Array,
                required: true,
                default: () => [],
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.');
        },

        computed:{},

        data: () => ({
            user: {
                permissionId: "",
            }
        }),

        methods: {},
    }
</script>
```

Then in your component template:

```
<select required v-model="user.permissionId" class="form-control" id="user-permissionId">
    <option v-for="permission in permissions" :value="permission.id" :key="permission.id">
        {{ permission.id }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: With your code everything is ok... but what is the problem in my code exactly?

Comment: I expanded my suggestion to hopefully help give a bit more insight. Let me know if you'd like more detail; always happy to help!